# Woocommerce Single Product Page, the Title, description and content all appear vertically below the product image

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

Woocommerce Single Product Page, the Title, description and content all appear vertically below the product image instead of the side of the image. I have not made any changes to the single product template etc.

[Link](https://off-size.com/shop/allclothes/promenade-top/) to the site.
Can anyone help me make the content title and description appear on the right side of the image? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float` property like this:

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {
float: left;
padding-left: 25px;
}
```